# Resources for Philosophy of Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, ressources

Are there any suggestions to go through the foundations and logic of mathematics step by step. I understand that there are lot of resources to go through but I keep losing motivation as these are quite voluminous. Hence I am looking for a step to step guide.

Comment: What's your objective? The foundations of math, logic, and the philosophy of math are three different things with some overlap.

Comment: The overlap of everything so that I can link up things.

Comment: See [Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/) for an overview.

Comment: There are some textbook recommendations in [Math SE, Good books on Philosophy of Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30572/152568).

Answer (score 1):

The book by Ian Stewart and David Tall, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-foundations-of-mathematics-9780198706434?cc=us&lang=en&#). In this book, he constructs some fundamentals of Mathematics (Number, Set, Functions, etc). From ideas from our daily experiences, he takes us to semi-advance ideas (Groups, Groupoids, Rings, Axiomatic Systems).